# Is inheritance useful in this case?

Tags: java, class, gis, class-diagram

I want to work on GIS and I am in conception step, and I have these kinds of roads (ways)

- Highway → Primary
- Highway → Secondary
- Highway → LivingStreet
- Highway → Tertiary
- Highway → Residential
- Highway → Unclassified
- Highway → Motorway
- Highway → Steps
- Highway → Footway
- Highway → Service
- Highway → Pedestrian
- Highway → SecondaryLink
- Highway → PrimaryLink
- Highway → Trunk
- Highway → Path
- Highway → TertiaryLink
- Highway → Track
- Highway → Cycleway
- Highway → Road
- Highway → MotorwayLink

I am using Java and my question is: Is it preferable to create for each one a class extending an abstract class ("way")? Or it is preferable to create theme just in one class and use an attribute `int highwayType` to differentiate between them, knowing that each one has its own drawing function and zoom level of drawing?

Comment: Coding behavior in an integer is too implementation-specific. That's something you'd store in a relational database, if at all. Do you want to differentiate between different types of highways in order to define different rendering functions?

Comment: my problem is that I am affraid to have problems in the future, for each way kind a manner of drawing, so if I use all in one class I have just to decide the function switch(highwayType),

Comment: @RiadSaadi Why not use `someWay instanceof SomeSubclass` comparisons?

Comment: @hexafraction you mean extending class??

Comment: @RiadSaadi Yes. Extending an (abstract/concrete) class, or implementing an interface.

Comment: thank you @hexafraction, I will do this...thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use integers to define the type of a class. Object-oriented programming makes it much easier.

You should have one abstract class *Highway*, which all your specific classes inherit from, e.g. `class PrimaryHighway extends Highway`. The abstract class would declare a method `render()`, which all subclasses then override with their specific behavior.

This way, you model the actual behavior in the subclasses – and when using highway objects, you don't have to find out which class you are using, because all highways support `render()`.

You could also create an interface `Drawable`, which all classes implement. The interface would require a method `render()` to be defined in each class that implements it. The benefit is that all things that are drawable could use this interface, and you wouldn't have to do the same thing all over again for all drawable things that aren't highways.

[image]

Comment: I think that it is better to implement `Drawable` in other classes : `Drawable1`, `Drawable2`, ... which override `render()`, after that instanciate in `primaryHighway` an attribute of `Drawable`. is it better? because maybe some subclasses of `Highway` will use the same render function or change it after during runtime

Comment: That sounds a little complicated. If some subclasses of `Highway` share the same rendering method, they should inherit from the same parent class. For example, if `Footway` and `Cycleway` have the exact same way to render, then have them both inherit from a `FooWay` (you choose a proper name), which again inherits from `Way`. It all depends on what GUI approach you have, of course. Perhaps you don't even want the drawing functionality in the models themselves.

Answer (score 2):

go through this link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

your class should have only a **single responsibilty**. using integers and if else will make it hard to test and maintain. you should go with inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, maybe you want to take it up a level and not try to model every conceivable geographic feature type in some class hierarchy.  I tend to avoid creating massive class hierarchies, particularly in Java where you have no multiple inheritance. You've got twenty classes for highways alone. I think that down this path madness awaits you.

You list a bunch of features that would appear to mirror some of those provided by [OpenStreetMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features#Highway). Why not just look at the sources for an existing Java-based OSM capability like [JOSM, the Java OpenStreetMap](http://josm.openstreetmap.de) Editor and learn from people who have been doing it for years how to  model geographic features as a collection of attributes on [objects](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help/Concepts/Object).

Better yet, instead of inventing your own Java based GIS - instructive as that might be in learning GIS, or Java, or object oriented programming - why don't you pick an existing project and contribute to improving that one or [some other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geographic_information_systems_software#Open_source_software).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, Yes these data come from OpenStreetMap, and I just took a small region to test my work. I am working with android to realize an Embedded GIS, if I take data.osm without some modification, the file will be biggest and a lot of other problems like the id of nodes is bigger than the Biggest value of int type, and I need direct coordinates of ways, not the pointer to nodes, I separate Areas from ways, ext... 
I want please just to know if I can see the source code of JOSM??
Thank you another time Mr @jwd630

Answer (score 1):

you can download [OReilly Head First Design Patterns.pdf](http://www.jtbookyard.com/uploads/6/2/9/3/6293106/head_first_design_pattern.pdf) it is a very nice book for design pattern and spoke exactly about your case in the first chapter.